# Solution simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm desperately trying to find the solution of this simple ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}= C +\frac{x-a_1}{b_1} + \frac{x-a_2}{b_2} $$

Where C is a constant.
Someone has a clue?

Thanks for the feedback already:
Ok some more info: I think I can solve this by substituting $x$ by $e^{t}$.
In that case I get:

$$ e^t = C+\frac{e^t-a_1}{b_1} + \frac{e^t-a_2}{b_2}$$
But now I'm stuck. Does it mean x is just:
$$ x (1-1/b_1 -1/b_2)= (C-a_1/b_a -a_2/b_2)  $$
But then it is no longer depending on t... Iḿ doing something wrong here

Comment: Welcome to math,SE. What do you find difficult in the question?? Have you tries separating the variables??

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

- Write the equation in the form: $x' + c_1 x = c_2$.
- Use an integrating factor or notice that the equation is separable.

Don't forget to handle any special cases when calculating $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Ok, but what would be the solution to  $x′+c_1x=c_2$?

Comment: @user44558 See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), particularly the first example. Which method(s) have you learned so far for solving linear first order differential equations?

Answer (score 1):

This is a time-invariant linear ODE with constant coefficients. The solution is therefore $x(t) = a+be^{\lambda t}$ for some $a,b,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. By substituting that for $x$ in your ODE and comparing the coefficients you can easily find the particular values of $a,b,\lambda$.